# Творческое заимствование?

Tags: css, bootstrap, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день, у меня проблема не могу вытащить слайдер товаров из этой бутcтреповской темы. Переношу в проект css и скрипты master-slider, но все равно слайдер не работает. Мне нужно именно он в мой дипломный проект, на этом настояла моя дипломная руководительница. 
Вот сама тема:
[bootstraplovers.com/templates/boland-shop-v1.1/pro](http://bootstraplovers.com/templates/boland-shop-v1.1/product-detail-1.html)

Вопрос что нужно еще перенести в проект что-бы этот слайдер работал.

P.S. Пытался перенести весь проект, но все равно слайдер не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Это вот он: http://www.masterslider.com/

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Я тружусь в Microsoft Visual Studio. А это для Wordpress. Как мне вытянуть этот слайдер оттуда?

Comment: я вожу экскаватор. А это для сарая. Как мне взять эту дверь оттуда?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Сейчас козырь крест?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там используется слайдер [masterslider.com](http://masterslider.com)
Вот здесь его код http://www.masterslider.com/wp-content/plugins/masterslider/public/assets/js/masterslider.min.js?ver=3.1.3
Здесь документация к нему http://masterslider.com/doc/